# Is there any way to print receipt using PHP?

Tags: php, printing, text-alignment, php-printer

I am trying this way, but its not producing proper alignment. I am trying to print using network printer "HP LaserJet Mono PCLmS Class Driver" in my LAN. Printing is works properly but alignment is not perfect.

```
$text1 = $this->string_align("Example item #1", "4.00");
$text2 = $this->string_align("Another thing tea", "3.50");
$text3 = $this->string_align("Something else", "1.00");
$text4 = $this->string_align("A final item", "4.45");
$text5 = $this->string_align("Subtotal", "12.95");
$text6 = $this->string_align("A local tax", "1.30");
$text7 = $this->string_align("Grand Total", "14.25");

$handle = printer_open("HP LaserJet Mono PCLmS Class Driver");
printer_start_doc($handle, "Recept Document");
printer_start_page($handle);
printer_draw_bmp($handle, "D:\\logo.bmp", 1, 1);
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 50, 70, 300, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);
printer_draw_text($handle, $text1, 100, 400);
printer_draw_text($handle, $text2, 100, 500);
printer_draw_text($handle, $text3, 100, 600);
printer_draw_text($handle, $text4, 100, 700);
printer_draw_text($handle, $text5, 100, 800);
printer_draw_text($handle, $text6, 100, 900);
printer_draw_text($handle, $text7, 100, 1000);
printer_delete_font($font);
printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close($handle);
exit;

function string_align($name = '', $price = '', $dollarSign = false){
$rightCols = 10;
$leftCols = 38;
if ($dollarSign) {
$leftCols = $leftCols / 2 - $rightCols / 2;
}
$left = str_pad($name, $leftCols) ;

$sign = ($dollarSign ? '$ ' : '');
$right = str_pad($sign . $price, $rightCols, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
return "$left$right\n";
}
```

Comment: Why not just output it and let the browser do the printing?

Comment: Try the `consolas` font.

Comment: @Andreas. Thanks for your comment. Receipt will print using scheduler, there is no way to use browser.

Comment: @HafizurRahman use http://printjs.crabbly.com/

Comment: @Sujit Agarwal, Thanks for your comment. Using **consolas** now its works perfectly.

Comment: adding it as answer so that people who later on see this question can get help.

Comment: @HafizurRahman - please mark the answer I submitted as correct using the tick mark on left. And meanwhile, welcome to stack overflow. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `consolas` font.

It's a uniform width font and should render properly on your printed page.

Comment: By the way, is there any PHP library to make it easy?

Comment: You're looking for a php library to make the printing easier?

Comment: Yes @Sujit Agarwal

Comment: Its not working with LAN printer "HP LaserJet Mono PCLmS Class Driver".

Comment: You mean the library?

Comment: Yes this **escpos-php ** library...... here is the issue https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/474 at windows...., I have tried also.